# Django : Getting an instace of a model based on a static location

Tags: django, model, orm

Lets say I have this model

```
class Egg(models.Model):
    file = FileField(upload_to='media')
    img = ImageField(upload_to='media')
```

How to get an Egg instance if I only have the file URL string like 'http://example.com/media/spam.tar.gz'? Can I query by this URL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of the url you want to query by? By `spam.tar.gz`? If so, you can try:

```
Egg.objects.filter(file__icontains='spam.tar.gz').
```

Comment: thanks, I didnt know that we can query a FileField by string.